# How to send a multipart REST Service request using UFT?

Tags: uft-api

I need to run rest API service with multipart using UFT.

We are trying to send a rest API request with multipart form data using UFT, but getting an unhandled exception error. We tried the option 'Multipart' of UFT with the below approaches.

Approach 1: Providing OAuth token info and request info(contains text and html tags) under Headers

Approach 2: Providing OAuth token info and request info under headers of parts

Approach 3: Providing OAuth token info and request info under parts.

We are successfully able to send a rest API form data request using post man tool. Followed the below approach.

Approach: providing OAuth token info under Authorization tab and request info(contains text and HTML tags) in the form of key-value pairs under form-data of Body.

And also we tried the same using Java HTTP client and successfully able to send a multipart form data.

But still no luck with HP UFT tool. Following is the user guide link for same. https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.51/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/task_http_mulitpart.htm

Using UFT we are successfully able to send JSON request without using multipart.

Still, we are trying with Multipart option of UFT.

How to send a multipart REST API request using Multipart option of UFT?

Comment: Hello there. This forum isn't about someone else doing your work / assignments on your behalf. It is about asking and getting help to explicit programming issues. If you have made any attempts to solve this yourself, please provide that information here - otherwise I don't think that you will be getting much help from this forum.

Comment: Hello ejuhjav, First fall thanks for your quick reply. Just I have updated approaches which are tried. Please help us on the above issue. Thanks in advance.